# Generating the same random number per column values

Tags: sql, random, concatenation, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, dml

I have a table which in which I would like to generate random numbers in a specific format (e.g. TEST-10256). For which I have been using the below:

```
concat('TEST-' , uniform(10000, 99000, RANDOM()))
```

However I now want to update a table with these random numbers based on two columns, so the desired outcome would be this:

[image]

I am not sure how to keep the same random value per previously matching it on the same values in ROW1 & ROW2.

Comment: What should be the value for `A, 13` - `TEST-10256` or other value?

Comment: it would be another value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on query from @Lukasz, we can use `update` statement.

-- Original

```
select * from test;
```

| ROW1 | ROW2 |
| --- | --- |
| A | 12 |
| A | 12 |
| B | 5 |
| B | 5 |
| C | 1 |
| C | 1 |
| D | 10 |

-- Update statement

```
update test t set t.row2 = t1.new_col
        from (select row1, row2, 
            CONCAT('TEST-' , uniform(10000, 99000, RANDOM())) new_col
            from (select distinct row1, row2 from test)
        )t1
    where t1.row1 = t.row1
        and t1.row2 = t.row2;
```

-- After update

```
select * from test;
```

| ROW1 | ROW2 |
| --- | --- |
| A | TEST-37642 |
| A | TEST-37642 |
| B | TEST-39082 |
| B | TEST-39082 |
| C | TEST-50195 |
| C | TEST-50195 |
| D | TEST-14564 |

Answer (score 1):

Step 1: Generate a temporary table for possible values:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TEMPORARY TABLE random_values
AS
SELECT ROW1, ROW2, CONCAT('TEST-' , uniform(10000, 99000, RANDOM())) AS new_value
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT ROW1, ROW2 FROM <table_name>) AS sub;
```

Step 2: Join using the newly generated and materialized values:

```
SELECT t.ROW1, rv.new_value AS ROW2
FROM <table_name> t
JOIN random_values rv
  ON t.ROW1 = rv.ROW1
 AND t.ROW2 = rv.ROW2;
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: The random() function gives a random number for each row, how can I keep the same random number for all rows where ROW1 = ROW1 and ROW2=ROW2?

Comment: @Python_Hey I have provided output as sample

Answer (score 0):

Try using the MERGE statement to populate your new field.  It allows you to fully run your query then apply its results as an UPDATE.

[You can get the syntax here](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/merge.html)